# How can inject Model to Presenter when create it wit dagger2?

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-mvp

I try create `MVP + dagger2`

I create Model **moudule:**

```
@Module
class ModelsModule {

    @Provides
    BasketModel provideBasketModel() {
        return new BasketModel();
    }

    @Provides
    ProductModel provideProductModel() {
        return new ProductModel();
    }
}
```

and I need create Presenters. My presenter must use model

**Presenters:**

```
public class ProductPresenter {

    private ProductModel;

    public ProductPresenter(ProductModel productModel) {
        this.productModel = productModel;
    }

   publict void test(){
      productModel.someMethod();
     }
```

And I can not set ProductModel  when create Presenter. Presenter I create like this:

```
@Module
public class PresentersModule {

    @Provides
    ProductPresenter provideProductPresenter() {
        return new ProductPresenter();//What I need set to constructor? new ProductModel()?
    }
```

Comment: Where is your component? How are you building your component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing `ProductModel` in your presenter class you also need to tell your `PresenterModule` how to construct your presenter :

```
@Module
public class PresentersModule {

@Provides
ProductPresenter provideProductPresenter(ProductModel model) {
    return new ProductPresenter(model);
    }
}
```

Dagger is clever enough to find out that you have already build your model instance in another `@Module` class.

I think you also need to annotate your Presenter's constructor with `@Inject` like :

```
@Inject
public ProductPresenter(ProductModel productModel) {
    this.productModel = productModel;
}
```

EDIT : And obviously you need a `@Component` interface. You haven't post any related code but I assume you have one.